# Can we claim that $\int\limits_{X} f(x)d\mu=\int\limits_{X_1} f(x)d\mu$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $X_1\in\mathfrak{M}$ with $\mu(X\setminus X_1)=0$ and $f:X_1\to [0,+\infty]$ be a measurable function.  Can I conclude that $$\int\limits_{X} f(x)d\mu=\int\limits_{X_1} f(x)d\mu$$

The integral on the RHS makes sense but on the LHS does not because function $f(x)$ is defined on $X_1\subset X$. Even $\mu(X\setminus X_1)=0$ I don't think that this notation is rigorous.

Would be grateful to read your comments, please!

Comment: For the LHS to make sense you need to replace f with a measurable extension to X. Then the equality holds

Comment: @JonathanHole Would it still hold if the extension is on the extended reals ($+\infty$ allowed)?

Comment: If the measure is complete, then you can trivially extend $f$ to a new function $F:X\to [0,\infty]$ by setting it $0$ elsewhere. Then, $F$ will be $\mathfrak{M}-\mathcal{B}_{[0,\infty]}$ measurable (the latter being Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,\infty]$). This is because if $U\in \mathcal{B}_{[0,\infty]}$, then $F^{-1}(U) = [F^{-1}(U)\cap X_1^c] \cup [F^{-1}(U)\cap X_1] = [F^{-1}(U)\cap X_1^c] \cup f^{-1}(U)$, this is a union of measurable sets (by completeness) hence measurable. Then, since $\mu(X_1^c)=0$, we can say that $\int_XF \, d\mu = \int_{X_1} F\, d\mu = \int_{X_1}f\, d\mu$.

Comment: @angryavian, good question. But it should be correct since if $F:X\to [0,+\infty]$ measurable extension of $f:X_1\to [0,+\infty]$ where $F=0$ on $X\setminus X_1$. Since $F\geq 0$ then $\int_{X}F(x)d\mu=\int_{X_1}F(x)d\mu+\int_{X\setminus X_1}F(x)d\mu=\int_{X_1}f(x)d\mu+\int_{X\setminus X_1}0d\mu=\int_{X_1}f(x)d\mu$. Looks correct to me.

Comment: @peek-a-boo, I guess that the completeness of the measure $\mu$ is abundant because if I define the new function $F$ on $X$ by $F(x)=0$ on $X\setminus X_1$ and $F(x)=f(x)$ on $X_1$ then $F(x)$ is still measurable function. Right?

Comment: I don't think it's redundant, because like I mentioned in my comment, you need completeness to deduce that the set $F^{-1}(U)\cap X_1^c$ is measurable (because completeness is what guarantees that all subsets of measure-zero sets are measurable)

Comment: @ZFR I agree that for your particular choice of extension, things are fine. My comment is more about what conditions we need on the extension to ensure the equality. (e.g., cannot allow $f$ to be $+\infty$ on $X \setminus X_1$?)

Comment: Maybe you are right. I have not read your reasoning in details yet. But let's take a look at my reasoning: We have to show that $F:X\to [0,+\infty]$ is measurable. Let $c\in \mathbb{R}$ the consider $F^{-1}((c,+\infty])=\{x\in X: F(x)>c\}=\{x\in X_1: F(x)>c\}\sqcup \{x\in X\setminus X_1: F(x)>c\}$. The first set is just $\{x\in X_1: f(x)>c\}=f^{-1}((c,+\infty])$ is measurable because $f$ measurable function. The second set is just $\{x\in X\setminus X_1: 0>c\}$ which is $\varnothing$ or $X\setminus X_1$.

Comment: So we get union of two measurable sets which is measurable. I guess we need completeness when we extend $f(x)$ arbitrarily. But here we extend by zero.

Comment: @peek-a-boo if the measure space is complete, then ANY extension of f is measurable for the reason you gave. But even in the incomplete case you can still obtain a measurable extension by setting it to be some constant value elsewhere

Comment: @JonathanHole, I am agree with you that instead of $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu$ we have to write $\int_X F(x)d\mu$ where $F(x)$ - measurable extension of $f(x)$ by zero. But as I asked above why in many books they do not write the integral of an extension but just $\int_{X}f(x)d\mu$ where $f(x)$ measurable function which is defined on $X_1$ where $\mu(X\setminus X_1)=0$. Could you explain it, please?

Comment: @JonathanHole Thanks for correcting me, having thought about it more, it seems almost obvious ;)

Comment: @Johanthan Hole, could you explain the question which I asked in the above comment, please?